# Why is the kernel of this homomorphism $P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and $P$ be a nonzero prime ideal of $R$. Let $\alpha\in P^n\setminus P^{n+1}$, so that $P^n=\alpha R+ P^{n+1}$. Consider the homomorphism $\phi: R\rightarrow P^n/P^{n+1}:a\mapsto a\alpha \mod P^{n+1}$. Then, why is the kernel of this homomorphism $P$?

If $\phi(a)=0$, then we have $a\alpha\in P^{n+1}$. From the choice of $\alpha$, we must have $a\alpha R= P^{n+1}$. Is this sufficient to prove that $a\in P$?

Comment: Clearly, if $p\in P$, then $p\alpha\in P^{n+1}$, so $p$ is in the kernel. Thus the kernel contains $P$ and since it is maximal, if $P$ is not the kernel, the kernel must be all of $R$. But, $1$ is not in the kernel.

Comment: @Mohan Aha! Thank you very much.